# Django log_update() got multiple values for argument 'user'

Tags: python, django

I'm getting TypeError log_update() got multiple values for argument 'user' when trying to create an instance in the database.

## Constructor

```
class ChangeLogManager(models.Manager):

    use_in_migration = True

    def log_update(user, content_type, object_id, content_object, changes, date_of_change):

        return self.model.objects.create(
            user = user,
            content_type = content_type,
            object_id = object_id,
            content_object = content_object,
            changes = changes,
            date_of_change = date_of_change,
        )
```

## views

```
def editUser(request, pk):

    # Query appropriate user based on pk returned in url
    user = User.objects.get(pk = pk)

    # Get the EditUserForm and add the user as instance
    edit_user_form = EditUserForm(instance = user)

    if request.method == 'POST':

        # Bind data to the form class, and add the user as instance
        edit_user_form = EditUserForm(request.POST, error_class=DivErrorList, instance = user)

        old_user_instance = User.objects.get(pk = pk)

        # Validate form inputs
        if edit_user_form.is_valid():

            # Save edits
            edit_user_form.save()

            # Log change
            ChangeLog.change_message(request.user.id, User, old_user_instance)
        else:
            # error

    context = {
        'user': user,
        'edit_user_form': edit_user_form,
    }

    # Render request, template and context
    return render(request, 'users/backend/user/user_edit.html', context)
```

## method

```
def change_message(request, obj, old_instance):

    new_instance = obj.objects.get(pk = old_instance.pk)

    ct = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(new_instance)

    for field in obj._meta.get_fields():
        if isinstance(field, models.ManyToOneRel):
            continue

        old_value = getattr(old_instance, field.name)
        new_value = getattr(new_instance, field.name)

        if old_value != new_value:
            change_message = json.dumps({"field": field.name, "old_value": old_value, "new_value": new_value})

            ChangeLog.objects.log_update(
                user = request,
                content_type = ct.pk,
                object_id = new_instance.pk,
                changes = change_message,
            )
```

The error happens on the line `user = request,`. I've tried looking at other threads, and adding both `self` and moving `request` as the first parameter in the method without luck. I've also read that its best practice to replace the method parameters with `**kwargs`, but as I'm quite new, I'm not sure how to retrieve the needed parameters in the method itself.

## edit - traceback

```
[28/Dec/2019 20:53:02] "GET /backend/users/1/edit/ HTTP/1.1" 200 30770
Internal Server Error: /backend/users/1/edit/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/daniel/Projects/proj/Code/puro/users/views.py", line 191, in editUser
    ChangeLog.change_message(request.user.id, User, old_user_instance)
  File "/Users/daniel/Projects/proj/Code/puro/utils/models.py", line 63, in change_message
    ChangeLog.objects.log_update(
TypeError: log_update() got multiple values for argument 'user'
```

Comment: Can you share the traceback?

Comment: The `ChangeLogManager.log_update` method should probably have "self" as the first parameter as it appears to be an instance method

Comment: Post updated with traceback :)

Comment: Have you tried adding "self" as the first parameter to "log_update"?

Comment: Adding `self`so it becomes `def log_update(self, user, content_type, object_id, content_object, changes, date_of_change):` gives the error `log_update() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'content_object' and 'date_of_change'`

Comment: You're not passing those arguments but the method requires them

Comment: Thank you, made it work now. Thought that if you left the arguments out, django would just use default instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `self` as the first argument to the `log_update` method and you need to pass the other required arguments to the method

```
ChangeLog.objects.log_update(
    user = request,
    content_type = ct.pk,
    object_id = new_instance.pk,
    content_object=new_instance,
    changes = change_message,
    date_of_change=datetime.datetime.now()
)
```